# Ruby array: getting all the elements that have the max value while chaining methods (namely, without having a handle on the sorted array)

Tags: arrays, ruby

Suppose that you need to get all the elements that have the max value in an array.

A possible method would be to `sort` the array then use `Enumerable#take_while`:

```rb
array = [ 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3 ].sort {|a,b| b - a}
array.take_while { |e| e == array[0] }
#=> [3, 3, 3]
```

Now, when you are ***beautifully*** chaining methods and don't want to stop the chain just for storing the sorted array (which you'll need for referencing its first element in the `take_while` block), how would you do it?

<sub>I posted the question and an answer below for reference, but I probably missed better ways, so feel free to post your own method</sub>

Comment: Maybe rephrase "all the best elements"? Without evaluation criteria, "best" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Maybe something like "all elements that have max value"?

Comment: Fravadona and @engineersmnky, regarding my now-deleted answer: whoops.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
arr = [ 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3 ]
```

```
arr.sort {|a,b| b - a}.tap { |a| a.select! { |e| e == a.first } }
  #=> [3, 3, 3]
```

Note that `arr` is not mutated.

Comment: `array.group_by(&:itself).max.last` is another option. And `array.tally` is not the same, but may be sufficient.

Comment: Note that all the comment above referred to my original answer, which was incorrect, or at least very inefficient.

Comment: Why did you use `sort` this time? Wouldn't it be possible to get the `max` just before doing the `select!` ?

Comment: @Fravadona, I didn't want to mutate `arr` and `arr.dup.tap { |a| mx = a.max; a.select! { |e| e == mx } }` doesn't seem like it meets the spirit of the question. Suggestion?

Comment: Oh! You're right about it. In my specific use-case it wasn't a problem because `arr` is generated by other functions prior in the chain, so I didn't take notice that the `sort` was for preserving the array.

Answer (score 1):

###### ruby < 2.5

- *My original response to the question*: `sort`.`slice_when`.`first`

```rb
[ 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3 ].sort {|a,b| b - a}.slice_when {|a,b| b != a}.first
#=> [3, 3, 3]
```

***note:** As `slice_when` returns an `Enumerator`, this solution won't walk through all the sorted array when chaining it with `first`. There is a more performant solution below tough.*

---

###### ruby >= 2.5

- *Combining @engineersmnky and @Cary methods:* `then` and `max`+`select`

```
[ 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3 ].then { |arr| mx = arr.max; arr.select { |elm| elm == mx } }
#=> [3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Ruby 2.5 added `yield_self` and ruby 2.6 aliased this as `then` so your original code can be changed to `array.sort.reverse.then {|a| a.take_while { |e| e == a[0] }}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
pry(main)> [ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 ].sort.slice_when {|a,b| b > a}.to_a.last 
=> [3, 3, 3]
```

A bit similar of the last solution but also different.

Source https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when

Comment: In this version, `slice_when` will walk the entire array, which is suboptimal.